# Idea: Add a "flag" link in the Revision history

Tags: feature-request, flags, edits, revision-history

I came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28582286/error-1064-when-running-create-table-script) in the Low Quality Posts queue (it was full of gibberish), and just out of curiosity I reviewed its [Edit history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/28582286/revisions)... It's one of those cases where the OP *vandalizes* his own post (I did what I think is right: I rolled back the edit).

It's not the first time I come across things like this (sometimes the OP does it, sometimes other users do it), but it seems to me that this kind of behavior is quite bad (to say it mildly).

So this idea popped out in my mind: Is it (would it be) possible to add some kind of flag link / button to flag this kind of vandalizing edits?

I know that issues can be addressed in the Edit review queue, but I think that putting a direct link in the Revision history would help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no need to add a flag button in the revision history of a post.

For issues that may occur, like a user defacing their post(s), a user leaving offensive edit summaries, etc, you simply need to flag the post itself as "other - needs ♦ moderator attention" and write a short description of what the issue is.

In this particular case you did a rollback which is fine. But if the user defaces it again, definitely just other flag for moderator attention, and they will likely either lock the post or suspend the user and likely inform them that this is not acceptable.